Warm Spots on LVP Floor After Carpet Replacement
I recently replaced the carpet in my home office with LVP flooring, and I've noticed something puzzling. This room has always been a little warmer than the rest of the house (about 3 degrees warmer on average), i mostly thought because my gaming computer is in here. However, since installing the LVP, I’ve noticed a specific 6x3 foot area of the floor that feels warm to the touch.
Initially, I thought it might be due to sunlight since this area gets some sun during the day. But even when I keep the blinds closed all day, the floor in that spot remains warm.
Does anyone have ideas on what might be causing this? Could it be something structural, like a hot water pipe or HVAC duct below the floor? Or is it related to the new flooring material?
I'd appreciate any advice on this topic.

LVP is better thermal conductor than a carpet and that is why you notice it more. As for what is underneath to warm it up, we can not answer

@DIY75, make that an answer for an upvote.

That makes sense, is there a temperature where i should be worried about what is happening underneath or is it fairly normal to have swings in temp of LVP flooring?

@terrabl, the flooring is not changing temperature it is manifesting other components acting on the flooring.  You do not need to worry that LVP is generating heat on its own.  You should investigate the cause now, so you can mitigate the issue if it appears there is a possibility of serious consequences, ( Damage to the flooring or other components and at worst fire.)
